# NullPointerException LinkedList reverse method

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception, null, doubly-linked-list

I'm stuck on this exercise where I have to implement a reverse method for a doubly linked list, which reverses the entire list. I'm  getting a NullPointerException in my for loop and I'm not sure how to solve it as in the exercise it is stated that I am not supposed to create new IntNode instances. I keep getting the exception even if I use an if-else statement if(current.next != null) ...
Any help would be much appreciated!

```
void reverse() {
        IntNode temp1;
        IntNode temp2;
        // TODO: Vervollständigen Sie die Methode wie in der Aufgabenstellung gefordert.
        
        this.last.next = this.last.prev;
        this.last.prev = null; 
        
        for (IntNode current = this.last.next; current != this.first; current = current.prev) {
                temp1 = current.next;

            current.next = current.prev;
            current.prev = temp1;
        }
        this.first.prev = this.first.next;
        this.first.next = null;
        
        temp2 = this.first;
        this.first = this.last;
        this.last = temp2;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). You should spend time debugging your program, going through line by line, or just reading the stack trace to identify the line causing the issue.

Comment: Hello helloworld123.  Welcome to the Stacks.  Have you walked through the code by hand with paper noting down latest values of variables for a simple case that cause the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a full executable example: the complete class and the execution data on which you're getting the Exception. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

As for each node you are swapping next and prev of current node therefore, the increment condition in for loop should be current = current.next instead of current = current.prev.

```
    void reverse() {
        IntNode temp1;
        IntNode temp2;
    
        this.last.next = this.last.prev;
        this.last.prev = null; 
    
        for (IntNode current = this.last.next; current != this.first; current = current.next) {
            temp1 = current.next;

            current.next = current.prev;
            current.prev = temp1;
        }
        this.first.prev = this.first.next;
        this.first.next = null;
    
        temp2 = this.first;
        this.first = this.last;
        this.last = temp2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When swapping, the next element to swap becomes the `next` of the current inspected node. So you need to set `current = current.next` for the next iteration of the loop.

You also dont need to swap the last and first element outside of the loop, you can just do this inside, when you change the condition of the for-loop: Start with the `last` node and go until the inspected `current` is `null`.

Here is a slightly shorter solution based on your code:

```java
public void reverse() {
  for (IntNode current = this.last; current != null; current = current.next) {
    IntNode temp1 = current.next;
    current.next = current.prev;
    current.prev = temp1;
  }
  
  IntNode temp2 = this.first;
  this.first = this.last;
  this.last = temp2;
}
```